# stat work at the command line but not when passed into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, stat

I am debugging a bash script (on ubuntu) to obtain an image file block size using `stat`. The result from `stat` is correct at the command line but not when passed into a variable (as it is in the script).

If I use the `stat` command at the command line, I get what I want (the number of blocks, %b):

```
stat --format=%b image.png
```

Output, e.g.:
`72`

But if I pass the same into a variable (at the command line or in a script), like so:

```
b = $(stat --format=%b image.png); echo $b
```

I get this output:

```
 15:16:57 up  3:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.52, 0.58, 0.59
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

Yet, when I "x check" my script with `/bin/bash -x ../script.sh`, the variable b, defined as above, except that the image filename is passed as a variable, is shown to hold this value:

```
+ b = 328
 15:47:39 up  4:18,  0 users,  load average: 0.52, 0.58, 0.59
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

What did I miss?

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Run in a folder containing image files to return the html <img /> links.

touch img_reflinks.html

generate_list ()
{
  ls  .| egrep '\.png|\.svg|.jpg|.jpeg|.tiff'
}

for f in $(generate_list)
do
    str=''
    style=''

    # the filename prints correctly:
    echo "$f"

    # this is the problematic assignment, as in CL:
    b = $(stat --format=%b "$f")

    style="\"width:" + "$b" + "px;\""

    str="<img src=\"" + "$f" + "\", style=" + "$style" + "/>\n"

    echo "$str" >> img_reflinks.html
done
```

Comment: Aren't you getting a pile of "command not found" type errors for this script?

Comment: Please explain the downvotes as they are totally [unwarranted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Thanks.

Comment: in bash no spaces are allowed surrounding = sign during assignment so its  `b=$(stat --format=%b "$f")`  and not  `b = $(stat --format=%b "$f")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No space allowed in a variable declaration; so instead of

```
b = $(stat --format=%b image.png); echo $b
```

do

```
b=$(stat --format=%b image.png); echo $b
```

And instead of

```
ls  .| egrep '\.png|\.svg|.jpg|.jpeg|.tiff'
```

do :

```
for i in *.png *.svg *.jpg *.jpeg *.tiff; do
    # ...
done
```